# old helper with updateOrcreate

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to use old helper with updateorcreate. I have a textarea for an about field. If the user has published something, the old text should be displayed when he wants to update. When I try to use the old helper `{{old('about', $profile->about)}}`

I get this error: Attempt to read property "about" on null. When I remove the old helper, write something then add the old helper, then it works. I understand that it is trying to retrieve something that isn't in the database. I tried making the about field nullable but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `$profile` is null in your case. Maybe a create form instead of edit?

Try to :

```
{{old('about', $profile->about ?? '')}}

or

{{old('about', optional($profile->about))}}
```

So that it uses empty string when old does not exist and profile either.

Comment: No, it's for updating a profile, so I have to use updateorcreate. The user doesn't submit his personal credentials when registering.